# can Any one suggest me how to begin with nested scroll view?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

I need to keep a scrollview of size our view size,in that large scrollview again i have to keep six image views and six scrollviews.Please,can any one suggest something how to start with it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the key line of code...

```
[aView addSubview:nextView];
```

Comment: Actually it is not working images are going in side of the another scroll views

Comment: if you're adding the images as a subview of the main scroll view then the only other problem I can see is that you're not positioning them properly. Have you got `[myImage setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)]`?